# Fullcalender next and previous make more function call in MVC4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have tried the code with Fullcalender.js and Moment(), in jquery..but i am getting so much function call on my single click for next and previous button ... plz help any one

```
  $(document).ready(function () {    
    var CalLoading = true;
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        defaultDate:moment(),
        editable: true,
        allDaySlot: false,
        selectable: true,
        slotMinutes: 15,
        events:  function (start, end, callback) {
               $.getJSON("@Url.Action("EventSummary")", function (locationsArray) {
                   var result = $(locationsArray).map(function () {
                       return {
                           title: this.title,
                           start: this.start,
                           end: this.end,
                           allDay: this.editable
                       };
                   }).toArray();
                   callback(result);
               });
           },
        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            alert('You clicked on event id: ' + calEvent.id
                + "\nSpecial ID: " + calEvent.someKey
                + "\nAnd the title is: " + calEvent.title);

        },

        eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {
            if (confirm("Confirm move?")) {
                UpdateEvent(event.id, event.start);
            }
            else {
                revertFunc();
            }
        },

        eventResize: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) {

            if (confirm("Confirm change appointment length?")) {
                UpdateEvent(event.id, event.start, event.end);
            }
            else {
                revertFunc();
            }
        },



        dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

            $('#eventTitle').val("");
            $('#eventDate').val(moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
            $('#eventTime').val(moment(date).format('HH:mm'));
            ShowEventPopup(date);
        },

        viewRender: function (view, element) {

            if (!CalLoading) {
                if (view.name == 'month') {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', sourceFullView);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', sourceSummaryView);
                }
                else {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', sourceSummaryView);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', sourceFullView);
                }
            }
        }

    });

    CalLoading = false;


});
```

It function call prev, it increments the call by twice with my each click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hai @Saneesh try this one....

```
events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
 $.ajax({
                        url : '@Url.Action("GetEvents","FullCalender")',
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            start: start.unix(),
                            end: end.unix()
                        },
                        success: function (doc) {
                                var events = [];
                                $.each(doc, function (i, item) {
                                //alert(item["title"]);
                                    events.push({
                                             title: $(this).attr('title'),
                                             start: $(this).attr('start'), // will be parsed
                                             end: $(this).attr('end')
                                           });
                                     });
                                        callback(events);
                               }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: It Ok Duplication stopped but still i have more function call in next and previous click

Comment: @saneesh, i need to clarify some doubts... here you had written  "  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', sourceFullView) " and "$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', sourceSummaryView); "

Comment: what is the use of these two lines ?

Comment: Its is similar function like function (start, end, callback) {
               $.getJSON("@Url.Action("Event--")", function (locationsArray) {
                   var result = $(locationsArray).map(function () {
                       return {
                           title: this.title,
                           start: this.start,
                           end: this.end,
                           allDay: this.editable
                       };
                   }).toArray();
                   callback(result);
               });
           }, for get Event with full description